# How can I extend the maximum category bit mask in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I have more than 8 different sprite types that I want to handle collisions for. I saw  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752418/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-categorybitmasks-allowed-in-sprite-kit) but I really didn't understand the approach and also don't know Objective-C. How can I cater for collisions when my sprites exceed 8?

```
let spriteCategory                : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
       .
       .
       .
let enemyPolyCategory             : UInt32 = 0x1 << 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpriteKit can handle up to 32 different categories

```
static let hero: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
static let ground: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let obstacle: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
...
static let potions: UInt32 = 0x1 << 30
static let warriors: UInt32 = 0x1 << 31
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't set my category bit mask well.

Comment: Remember also that although there are only 32 different categories, a sprite can have more than one category. So 6 objects of type `smallAsteroid`, `asteroid` &  `largeAsteroid` and  `smallAlien`, `alien` and `largeAlien` can be represented by 4 categories - `asteroid`, `alien`, `small` & `large` (You could also have a `medium` category). This does need to be handled differently in `didBegin(contact:)` though.